# Unable to send email via smtp.gmail.com without enabling 'Access for less secure apps' flag

Tags: spring, email, spring-boot, smtp, gmail

Gmail prevents sending email if '*[Access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)*' is not Turned On,

I am using spring-boot and sending email using class:

```
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
```

It fails with message:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14
```

It works only if I enable the flag '*Access for less secure apps*', I want to send an email without enabling that flag, any suggestions?

here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender emailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    javaMailSender.setPort(465);
    javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(getMailProperties());
    javaMailSender.setUsername(from);
    javaMailSender.setPassword(password);
    return javaMailSender;
}


    private Properties getMailProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to use Gmail within my website to send and receive mails. How can i Achieve that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159384/i-want-to-use-gmail-within-my-website-to-send-and-receive-mails-how-can-i-achie)

Comment: not a duplicate, my question is about how to solve the security requirement expected by Gmail.

Comment: I just retract the flag. However, there are many similar question, like http://stackoverflow.com/q/35550064. You can find the solution in these questions.

Comment: Looks like it is not possible with the current configuration.
One of the solutions found here: http://mydigitalbricks.blogspot.de/2016/03/gmail-oath2-with-spring-and-javamail.html